# Angular 2 items don't update when changed from phonegap notification dialog

Tags: cordova, angular, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, angular2-template

I am building an phonegap app with angular2. 
I want to show a confirmation dialog and in success callback to update elements from angular2 view. When I do this nothing happens right away, but if I update other model on the page (what is linked with angular) my update is updated.

For confirmation dialog I use phonegap plugin: `cordova-plugin-dialogs` and the method called is: `navigator.notification.confirm(...)`.

Here is my full code of my Component:

```
AboutComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: 'rl-about',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/about/view.html',
        directives: [TopBarComponent, ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: [Config, function(config) {
            this.config = config;

            this.title = "About";
            this.top_bar_left = "Back";
        }],
        /**
         * Back btn
         */
        topBarLeftClick: function(){
            window.history.back();
        },
        changeMessage: function(){
            this.message = "Test";
            var self = this;
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                "Delete this?",
                function(buttonIndex) {
                    if(buttonIndex == 1) {  //1 = Ok
                        console.log("Message before: " + self.message)  //self.message has the old value ("Test")
                        self.message = "Deleted";
                        console.log("Message after: " + self.message) //self.message has the new value ("Deleted"), but nothing changed on view.html
                    }
                },
                "Confirm Delete",
                ["Delete", "Cancel"]
            );
        }
    });
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <rl-top-bar [title]="title" [top_bar_left]="top_bar_left" (topBarLeftClick)="topBarLeftClick()" ></rl-top-bar>
    <div class="about-info-wrapper">
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="other_model" id="itemtoclick"/>
        {{message}}
        <div (click)="changeMessage()">click here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`{{message}}` is not updating when the callback of `navigator.notification.confirm` is called, but it's updated if I click for example on `input` box which is linked to an angular model

One hack that I found that is working is to click something from javascript when callback is called. Like this: `window.document.getElementById('itemtoclick').click()`

I try to add `.bind(this)` to `navigator.notification.confirm(...)` but it's throwing error.

I try to save `this` to a variable before calling `navigator.notification.confirm` but same result.

Same result if I `.bind(this)` to callback method.

Somehow I have reference to this inside callback because I can read and update, but angular2 doesn't know that I made a change to update the view.

Also this problem is only on mobile, if I try to run on browser (chrome) it's working ok. I use phonegap build to create the .apk file for android.
But the problem is also visible if I use Phonegap mobile app for live testing.

I want to know if there is a solution that will not involve a hack like this.

**Edit**

This is my first phonegap app

For Android I am using phonegap build

For iOS I am using phonegap CLI

The problem is in both Android and iOS.

**Edit 1 Apr 2016**

I created a video to better describe the problem: [See here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOIos6MPjLnYjFuVcbYefUpGfmfKF4INvn0oZnFEXGyrXsSkeO3ToDcgoPXwgbRFg/photo/AF1QipOq3pxjtX7eoxMLeWltX67nkfcQv4Oew5y2R8ui?key=MDNUaXhzejV2R2ZZUDkyY2E0R3hHamFYdlo4cnp3)

Also I change to not using `this` for `onDeviceReady` and the problem is still here.
Here is my main.js code:

```
var phonegapApp = {
    initialize: function() {
        phonegapApp.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', phonegapApp.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        console.log("phonegapApp onDeviceReady");
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent,[
            ng.http.HTTP_PROVIDERS,
            ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            new ng.core.Provider(ng.router.LocationStrategy, {useClass: ng.router.HashLocationStrategy})
        ]);
    }
};
```

And from `index.html` I call `phonegapApp.initialize();` at the bottom of my `body`.

Comment: How is this related to Phonegap?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 because I use a phonegap plugin: `cordova-plugin-dialogs` and only when I use this plugin I see this problem. And the problem in only on mobile (not browser). So it's related to this plugin.

Comment: That important information is not in your post. How do you expect people to solve your issue if you leave out important information?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I updated my question to explain better. I hope now I didn't omit something. Thanks.

Comment: Okay. we can now get tot the issues. The following questions will help me formulate an answer. Is this your first hybrid App? Are you using the Desktop App? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I updated my question with answer of you questions.

Comment: Again, Are you using the *Phonegap Desktop App*? What do mean you are using CLI for iOS \_AND\_  *Phonegap Build* for Android? This completely defeats the purpose of using either FOR someone doing this for the first time.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I am not using Desktop App. I just wanted to let you know that the error is in both situations if I use Phonegap Build or Phonegap CLI. So I think the error is not related to this because both work the same for this error case.

Comment: QUOTE: * So I think the error is not related to this because both work the same for this error case.* This is a rather broad assumption - possibly erroneous. I'm reviewing your information in full. This will take some time.

Comment: Okay. I think your issue is with the `this` statement. I don't know Angular well enough to find Angular errors, but these notes might help. This is an incomplete blog post: [Using this correctly, requires knowing the context.](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/using-this-correctly.md)

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I update my question. I change to not use `this` for `onDeviceReady` and the problem is still here (nothing changed). I created a video also to better describe the problem.  In `AboutComponent` I have to use `this` to have access to that component.

Comment: No one "needs" to use `this`. I will review your updates.

Comment: FWIW: you should be able to test this code outside of phonegap - test in your webbrowser. NOTE: This does not guarantee that it will work in phonegap.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 I tested in browser and it's working ok. The problem is only on mobile (both android and ios). If I test on mobile browser it's working ok. If I install the app from Play Store/TestFlight or using Phonegap App I see the problem.

Comment: Yes. I see that now, but I don't get the new code (the third  section). Explain third section please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107945/discussion-between-daniel-dudas-and-jessemonroy650).

Comment: Did you watch the [2nd video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ_YD4Ljbqc) in the list I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use an arrow function to be able to use lexical this:

```
this.message = "Test";
navigator.notification.confirm(
  "Delete this?",
  (buttonIndex) => {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {  //1 = Ok
        this.message = "Deleted";
    }
  },
  "Confirm Delete",
  ["Delete", "Cancel"]
);
```

See this link for more hints about the lexical this of arrow functions:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

**Edit**

If you use ES5, you could try:

```
this.message = "Test";
var self = this;
navigator.notification.confirm(
  "Delete this?",
  function(buttonIndex) {
    if(buttonIndex == 1) {  //1 = Ok
        self.message = "Deleted";
    }
  },
  "Confirm Delete",
  ["Delete", "Cancel"]
);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use plain javascript. If I try to use this method I get error from grunt: `Unexpected token: operator (>).`

Comment: Yes, it's an ES6 feature. You could try to save the `this` keyword outside the callback. I updated my answer accordingly...

Comment: Still not working this way. I put inside the callback this code: `console.log("Message before: " + self.message);
                        self.message = "Deleted";
                        console.log("Message after: " + self.message);` and it's updated ok (second console.log it's with Deleted message). But the view still don't refresh to display the new message. If I change anything else on the page without interacting with this it's updated.

Comment: Zones is responsible to trigger change detection of Angular2. Are you sure to have included this library when packaging your APK bundle?

Comment: I include this 4 files: `es6-shim.min.js, angular/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js, angular/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.umd.js, angular/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-all.umd.js`

Comment: Could you provide the complete code of your component? Thanks!

Comment: "If I change anything else on the page without interacting with this" -> how do you change things?

Comment: I updated the code with full component class and the html. With changing anything I mean for example in the code above if I click on the input and start typing in that field.

Comment: The input should be linked to a angular2 model (even if I don't use that model anywhere in my component). If I remove [(ngModel)] than the message it's still not updating.

Comment: I updated my question with a video so you can see the problem that I am facing better. You can see that when I click Delete nothing changed to `message` (In console I see that it had been changed). After I edit something else on screen (for example the input field in this example) the `message` is updated in view. Input field is not related to `message`.